# Using a dictionary and randomly choosing a value from multiple options

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I made a list with 3 values inside it, it looks like this

```
A = ["+","-","*"]
```

and basically I have this line later on

```
a = random.choice(A)
```

It's some work where I have to make a random quiz using those 3 operators, and I was told I have to use a dictionary to attain a higher mark, however, I am not sure how to make a dictionary 'key' with the 3 operators attached, AND, the operator has to be randomly selected. but I have no idea how to randomly select a value from a dictionary and use it in an if statement.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider rephrasing your question...

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate a dictionary however you like using whatever you prefer for keys. In this case, I just use simple numeric constants that have an arbitrary relationship to the operator.

```
 A = {0:"+", 1:"-", 2:"*"}
```

Then

```
a = A[random.choice(A)]
```

OR:

```
a = random.choice(A.values())
```

Or, to use the operators *as* keys and storing some additional detail in the values:

```
A = {"+":"addition", "-":"subtraction", "*":"multiplication"}

a = random.choice(A)  # returns a random operator

# display detail of the operator:

print A[a]
```

Comment: It is not necessary to call keys() in the argument to choice. Iterating over a dict will give you the keys.  `a = random.choice(A)` is sufficient (and I think nicer-looking).